# bind 'lateinit' modifier with condition in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, we have `lateinit` modifier to lazy variable initialization instead of `var something: Something? = null`.

In my situation, I have a list of the `Element`, and I want to **assign it to the `lateinit` variable when I having the first object.**

So, I tried several methods to achieve this.

**First**, using 'firstOrNull()' methods

```
lateinit var applicationHolder: ApplicationHolder

applicationHolder = env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(InjectApplication::class.java)
        .map {
            ApplicationHolder(it, (it as TypeElement).asClassName(), it.simpleName.toString()).apply {
                val component = it.getAnnotation(InjectApplication::class.java).getComponent()
                componentClass = component
            }
        }.firstOrNull()
```

The first solution was failed because `applicationHolder` doesn't accept the Nullable type of ApplicationHolder. (Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is ApplicationHolder? but ApplicationHolder was expected.)

Although I can use `first` instead of `firstOrNull` to achieve this, it's too dangerous because the list can be empty.

**Second**, using if-condition

```
val item = env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(InjectApplication::class.java)
        .map {
            ApplicationHolder(it, (it as TypeElement).asClassName(), it.simpleName.toString()).apply {
                val component = it.getAnnotation(InjectApplication::class.java).getComponent()
                componentClass = component
            }
        }.firstOrNull()

if (item != null) {
    applicationHolder = item
}
```

The second solution was succeeded to compile and working well.

**Third**, using backing properties (Actually, this solution don't use lateinit modifier)

```
val applicationHolder: ApplicationHolder
    get() {
        return _applicationHolder ?: throw NullPointerException("Not initialized")
    }

private var _applicationHolder: ApplicationHolder? = null

_applicationHolder = env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(InjectApplication::class.java)
        .map {
            ApplicationHolder(it, (it as TypeElement).asClassName(), it.simpleName.toString()).apply {
                val component = it.getAnnotation(InjectApplication::class.java).getComponent()
                componentClass = component
            }
        }.firstOrNull()
```

The third solution was succeeded to compile and working well.

In short, my question is as follows.

1. Is there a better solution to achieve my goal than these solutions?
2. If another solution doesn't exist, which is a clean or better solution? I can use the second or third solution but I have no confidence which is clean or better.

Comment: If the list is empty do you want to keep applicationHolder uninitialized or do you want to throw an exception?

Comment: Since that part is library code, I think it's better to leave uninitialized it than to throw an exception.

Comment: Then you should use the second variant because that will keep the variable uninitialized if the list is empty. If you were to add `?: throw NullPointerException("Not initialized")` to the first variant than it would compile and it would be equivalent to the third variant(both throwing an exception when the list is empty). I'm not sure how you would make it better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try to think more about it according to the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using lateinit over a nullable type here?

This strikes warning bells to me :

> it's too dangerous because the list can be empty.

If you try to access a lateinit object without initialising it, your application will crash. Lateinit should be use if it will definitely be initialised.

I would change the code to what you were avoiding : `var something: Something? = null`

Then use the firstOrNull() method. The kotlin null safety type system will enforce you deal with nulls, leading to safe code!

Comment: As you say, using lateinit in this situation (if the variable can be null) is not appropriate. So I changed `applicationHolder` to the nullable variable and implement checking logic when trying to use this variable. Thanks for the clear answer!

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to check whether a `lateinit` has been initialised, by calling `this::applicationHolder.isInitialized`.  (This was introduced in Kotlin 1.2; info [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#checking-whether-a-lateinit-var-is-initialized).)

However, as per @user8159708's answer, it still smells a bit.  Reworking to make the property nullable will make it slightly more awkward to access, but much safer.